# dynamically adding sets of form elements n times

Tags: php, javascript, forms, select

i'm working on an application that lets users enter the opening hours for a restaurant. i have the form code set up like this:

```
<div class="hourswrapper">
            Days:
            <input type="checkbox" name="day1[]" value="1" />M
            <input type="checkbox" name="day1[]" value="2" />Tu
            <input type="checkbox" name="day1[]" value="3" />W
            <input type="checkbox" name="day1[]" value="4" />Th
            <input type="checkbox" name="day1[]" value="5" />F
            <input type="checkbox" name="day1[]" value="6" />Sa
            <input type="checkbox" name="day1[]" value="7" />Su
            <br />
            Opening Time:
            <select name="starthour1">
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="01">1</option>
                <option value="02">2</option>
                <option value="03">3</option>
                <option value="04">4</option>
                <option value="05">5</option>
                <option value="06">6</option>
                <option value="07">7</option>
                <option value="08">8</option>
                <option value="09">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
            </select> : 
            <select name="startminute1">
                <option value="00">00</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="45">45</option>
                <option value="59">59</option>
            </select> 
            <select name="startwhen1">
                <option value="am">am</option>
                <option value="pm">pm</option>
            </select><br />
            Closing Time:
            <select name="endhour1">
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="01">1</option>
                <option value="02">2</option>
                <option value="03">3</option>
                <option value="04">4</option>
                <option value="05">5</option>
                <option value="06">6</option>
                <option value="07">7</option>
                <option value="08">8</option>
                <option value="09">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
            </select> : 
            <select name="endminute1">
                <option value="00">00</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="45">45</option>
                <option value="59">59</option>
            </select> 
            <select name="endwhen1">
                <option value="am">am</option>
                <option value="pm">pm</option>
            </select><br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="24hours[]" value="yes" />Open 24 Hours
        </div>
```

so basically the person chooses a set of hours and marks which days those apply to. of course there might be multiple sets of hours (ex. if a restaurant is open 12-2 one day but 12-5 another). i'd like to have a "Add More Hours" button that duplicates this same code when pressed, however many times is necessary.

what's the best way to go about this? how do you dynamically add a form element without needing to have it hidden at the beginning? how do i set different numbered names for each set of hours inputs, and later know how many to access (using PHP post)? i assume i'll need a javascript function that keeps track of how many have been added.

alternatively, i am open to suggestions on how to present hours inputs differently/better, perhaps a way that doesn't require dynamic creation of form elements. i do want to restrict the user's inputs so i don't have to worry about parsing weird entries, which is why i don't want to just have an text input box for each day.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_node.asp

Particularly the cloneNode and appendChild methods

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to use JavaScript/JQuery to dynamically add new elements, then use foreach in your PHP script to process all the inputs?

Hope this helps.

Y.J.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick little example of duplicating the hours input based on which checkbox is checked. Each hours div gets its' own unique id (see the `attr('id',hrsDivID)` part of the code below). Mimic this to rename your inputs/selects. See http://jquery.com/ and http://api.jquery.com/ for more.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/shared/javascript/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="hours" style='display:none'>
    Opening Time:
    <select name="starthour1">
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="01">1</option>
        <option value="02">2</option>
        <option value="03">3</option>
        <option value="04">4</option>
        <option value="05">5</option>
        <option value="06">6</option>
        <option value="07">7</option>
        <option value="08">8</option>
        <option value="09">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
    </select> : 
    <select name="startminute1">
        <option value="00">00</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="45">45</option>
        <option value="59">59</option>
    </select> 
    <select name="startwhen1">
        <option value="am">am</option>
        <option value="pm">pm</option>
    </select><br />
    Closing Time:
    <select name="endhour1">
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="01">1</option>
        <option value="02">2</option>
        <option value="03">3</option>
        <option value="04">4</option>
        <option value="05">5</option>
        <option value="06">6</option>
        <option value="07">7</option>
        <option value="08">8</option>
        <option value="09">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
    </select> : 
    <select name="endminute1">
        <option value="00">00</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="45">45</option>
        <option value="59">59</option>
    </select> 
    <select name="endwhen1">
        <option value="am">am</option>
        <option value="pm">pm</option>
    </select><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="24hours[]" value="yes" />Open 24 Hours
</div>
Days:
<div id='day1'>
            <input type="checkbox"  name="day1[]" value="1" onClick="addHours('day1');" >M
</div>
<div id='day2'>
            <input type="checkbox" name="day1[]" value="2" onClick="addHours('day2');" />Tu
</div>
<div id='day3'>
            <input type="checkbox" name="day1[]" value="3" onClick="addHours('day3');" />W
</div>
<div id='day4'>
            <input type="checkbox" name="day1[]" value="4" onClick="addHours('day4');" />Th
</div>
<div id='day5'>
            <input type="checkbox" name="day1[]" value="5" onClick="addHours('day5');" />F
</div>
<div id='day6'>
            <input type="checkbox" name="day1[]" value="6"  onClick="addHours('day6');"/>Sa
</div>
<div id='day7'>
            <input type="checkbox" name="day1[]" value="7"  onClick="addHours('day7');"/>Su
</div>
<script>
function addHours(divID){
    var d = document.getElementById(divID);
    var hrsDivID = divID+'_hours_div';
    $('#hours').clone().attr('id',hrsDivID).css('display','').appendTo(d);
    return false;
}
</script>
```